# python dataframe date on second row instead of header row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

i have a dataframe downloading as:

[the dataframe with the date header on a separate row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWqeL.png)

if i export it to a csv file and import it again it has all the headers on the first row.

if i look for the information from the row via .iloc[0] i get:

```
bidopen        1.14140
bidclose       1.14143
bidhigh        1.14160
bidlow         1.14116
askopen        1.14153
askclose       1.14164
askhigh        1.14179
asklow         1.14127
tickqty     5204.00000
Name: 2022-01-14 21:00:00, dtype: float64
```

resetting the index does not work

essentially i am trying to be able to select the date column, i.e. df['date'] etc, but with no luck in its current form.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code will let you switch the date as a columns and reset your index. You will need to import pandas

```
df['Date'] = df.index
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```